# Where can I find photos with EXIF data online for learning purposes?

Tags: metadata, tutorial, picture-samples

Many of the blogs / Flickr streams do not publish images their EXIF data with the pictures - all I can see is the histogram.

Can you recommend blogs / samples with EXIF data in them so that I may learn from them?

Comment: For Flickr, it's worth noting that showing/hiding EXIF is a user preference. Some *do* show it.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is an option by the user posting the picture.  Flickr for example - you can choose to show or hide the EXIF data on photos on your own stream....

Comment: Ooops just noticed that Dan Wolfgang said exactly this in his comment - before I answered.  Honest mistake - didn't see that before.

Comment: it's still a valid answer :)

Comment: I figured it wasn't really ans answer; more of a correction to the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Fotki show EXIF if the user desires](http://www.fotki.com)

My photos on Fotki have limited EXIF accessible by clicking a link next to the file.
 However, if you click the "Download original File" icon at top right of the image.
 Thusly

[image]

you'll get the uploaded original (if available) which may have the full EXIF embedded.

Whether any photos of mine are worth learning anything from is in the eyes and mind of the beholder, but many have EXIFs, if of interest.

eg this one ["Through the bars"](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/atw/rm01/through-the-bars.html#media)  has brief EXIF via link and full EXIF embedded.
 Main point here is total vanishing of cage bars by locating  them well inside focal length of lens, and f/1.8 DOF.

Similarly here [2000 Years!](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/atw/rm01/atw1102-dsc01776.html) - through glass.  While it's "hand held" without flash, shutter speed tells you it was VERY well braced (against glass and 'me', with me wedged against a pillar.

Not stunning as a photo  ['Closeup'](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/atw/rm01/dsc05633-10100212.html#media) but focal length may (or may not) be a surprise.
[Focal length, aperture](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/atw/rm01/ivsd-pict3528s-70.html) - Hobson's choice.

---

If a site permits saving an image it is sometimes found that EXIF data is present. If so this can then be viewed with any usual EXIF capable viewer.

Comment: +1 for using the word "thusly"!

Comment: The UI has changed since Russell's answer, but you can now obtain direct a link to the image files on Fotki by clicking the "Share" button just above the photo.

Answer (score 2):

The pictures might have the exif data despite not being displayed wherever they are being hosted, this [website](http://regex.info/exif.cgi/) can help see the exif data of a picture if you have the desire to know what's "behind" it.

Also there are plugins for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/exif?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=exif) that allow you to see a picture exif data.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [deviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/). If the user provides a photo with exif data there, it is shown on the lower right of the picture display page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome I recommend you "Exif Viewer"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nafpfdcmppffipmhcpkbplhkoiekndck

Answer (score 1):

One site that I've found particularly helpful in understanding what settings to use is [PixelPeeper.com](https://pixelpeeper.com/), in particular its [advanced search page](https://pixelpeeper.com/adv/). On the search page you can put in various search constraints on lenses, cameras, ISO, aperture etc and have it search flickr for images that matches those constraints.

So say that you want to search for how to take a good night shot with your lens you can select your lens and put a 1s+ limitation on the exposure time and look for night shots in the results. The page displays lens, camera, ISO, focal length, aperture and shutter speed right underneath the images.

If you're browsing for inspiration I've found that users on [500px.com](https://500px.com/) seem to be relatively good at exposing their photo metadata as well.